# WebSocket clinet over wss (SSL Handhake error)

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, client

I need to create websocket client which will work over secure connection.
I don't have experience with this kind of connection.

My code looks like below:

```
  @ClientEndpoint
public class WSClient {

    public static final String URL = "wss://endpoint.com:443/ws-live";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

        System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_FILE, "src/test/resources/clientkeystore.jks");
        System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_FILE, "src/test/resources/clientkeystore.jks");
        System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, "pass123");
        System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD, "pass123");

        SslEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SslEngineConfigurator(new SslContextConfigurator());

        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngineConfigurator);

        try {
            client.connectToServer(WSClient.class, URI.create(URL));
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But I receive an error when connecting:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:717)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:871)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:516)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:322)
    at com.bbh.systems.fx.etrading.automation.bbhlive.order.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:33)
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 200.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Response 200 means that connection didn't switch to websocket protocol.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try adding "-Djavax.net.debug=all" to your app server JVM_OPTIONS or if its a stand alone application - add it after the "java" command.  It will produce a ton of output but allow you to see why the handshake is failing.

Comment: What's your server endpoint looks like?